# vector <T *> destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I have a class defined like:

```
Class A
{
public:
    int num;
    A *parent;
    vector<A *> children;
    ...

    // constructor without parameters
    A(void)
    {
        this->num = 3;
        this->parent = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<num;++i)
            children.push_back(new A(this,num-1));
    }

    // constructor with parameters
    A(A *a,int n)
    {
        this->num = n;
        this->children->parent = a;
        for (int i=0;i<num;++i)
            this->children.push_back(new A(this,this->num-1));
    }
};
```

now, the constructor works fine. there are some problem with destructor.
currently, the destructor is defined as:

```
A::~A(void)
{
    if (this->parent!=0) this->parent = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<(int)children.size();++i)
        this->children[i]->~A();
    vector <A *> ().swap(this->children);
}
```

but every time when I debug it, it will break at:

```
void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type)
    {    // deallocate object at _Ptr, ignore size
    ::operator delete(_Ptr);
    }
```

it looks like I cannot delete the pointer in the vector of this->children, is there any way that I can de-construct the class successfully?

Comment: Aside: why are you casting `children.size()` to `int`, when you could just declare the loop variable as `size_t`?

Comment: If you use a `vector<shared_ptr<A> >` you won't need any of that code *and* your program will be more robust. Is that an option?

Comment: It's called _destructor_, not _deconstructor_

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* that this line won't compile: `this->children->parent = a;`

Comment: @larsmans: better to use `vector::size_type` instead of `size_t` directly.  All STL containers have a `size_type` typedef, as they don't all use `size_t`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `size_type` is defined as `size_t` for the default allocator. While I applaud genericity and standards compliance, I do find `std::vector<A*>::size_type` too much typing. (`auto` is even better, though.)

Comment: @larsmans: depending on which STL implementation you use, `vector::size_type` might not be using the `size_type` of the default allocator, but may be using `size_t` directly, or something else entirely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I just looked it up in the C++ standard and it seems you're right. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: Closing because OP explained that there was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

Your destructor should be:

```
A::~A(void)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i < children.size(); ++i)
        delete children[i];
}
```

You should probably also look into copy constructors. Otherwise, code like this will fail:

```
{
    A foo;
    B bar = foo;
}
```

Becuase you will delete the same pointers twice.

One of these two posts may help you with understanding that: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740471/c-copy-constructor-pointer-object) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781760/how-to-define-a-copy-constructor-with-pointers-in-it)

Answer (score 1):

in the destructor of A, you shouldn't call the destructors of child items explicitly, instead, just delete the elements of the vector. this should be sufficient for your purpose:

```
A::~A(void)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<children.size(); ++i)delete children[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor with parameters has a typo bug in it - `this->children->parent` will not compiler as `children` is not a pointer nor does `vector` have a `parent` member.  I suspect you meant to use `this->parent` instead.

Your destructor is directly calling the destructor of each child object, which will destroy the child but NOT free its memory.  You allocate the child objects with the `new` operator, so you need to use the `delete` operator to call the destructor and free the memory correctly.

On a side note, your `num` member is redundant.  You can use `children.size()` wherever `num` is needed.

Try this instead:

```
class A 
{ 
private:
  static const int default_num = 3;

public: 
    A *parent; 
    vector<A *> children; 
    ... 

    // default constructor
    A() 
    { 
        parent = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < default_num; ++i) 
            children.push_back(new A(this, default_num-1)); 
    } 

    // constructor with parameters 
    A(A *a, int n) 
    { 
        parent = a; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
            children.push_back(new A(this, n-1)); 
    } 

    ~A()  
    {  
        parent = 0;  

        for (vector<A *>::size_type i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i)  
            delete children[i];  
        /*
        alternatively:
        for (vector<A *>::iterator i = children.begin(); i != children.end(); ++i)  
            delete *i;  
        */

        children.clear(); // optional, will be handled when vector is implicitally destructed
    }  
};
```